# What is a mimic's "true form"?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters

The D&D 5E Monster Manual's entry for mimics it mentions that it "reverts to its true form when it dies."

I'm assuming a chest isn't its true form. What actually is its true form?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

According to the MM, page 220, its true form is amorphous.  That means that *it is without form in its true state*.  You could describe it as *a blob*.

> Shapechanger.  The mimic can use its action to polymorph into an
>   object or back into its true, amorphous form.

[Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/amorphous) definition:

> a·mor·phous (adjective)
>   əˈmôrfəs
>   *without a clearly defined shape or form.*

Answer (score 2):

I always envisioned the mimic as some sort of slime in its natural form.

The Monster Manual states that the Mimic returns to it's "amorphous form" when slain, and the definition of amorphous is "without a clearly defined shape or form."

Answer (score -1):

I would say that since the true form is amorphous and since the mimic has a huge mouth and a bunch of eyes, I'd say it's probably similar to a gibbering mouther.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).