# What is a Shadow (monster) made of consistency-wise?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters

In a game I am playing, one of our players ran across a thin beam whilst being chased by a shadow. The shadow, not wearing appropriate footwear, slips and falls down the well. We the players would repeat this for best results, and why not?

This resulted in a number of questions however.
How many shadows can fit into a well?
Can they climb without the ability to grapple anything?
Can they stack on one another?

One player pointed out that shadows were paper-thin and almost two dimensional back in 1st and 2nd editions (their write-up suggests they fit through small cracks and thin passages). By 3rd edition and Pathfinder they were dark ghosts, able to sort of *submerge* into the ground and easily wipe out entire villages just by touching anyone who walked down a poorly lit pathway.

Apparently in 5e they are [different again](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/shadow), squeezing down to an inch or so (without squeezing). They cannot be grappled - but does that mean that they cannot grapple?
How well can they fit together?
How many would fit into a phone booth?

It would be ideal if we knew if they were more like a balloon, as a jello blob, a fog patch, a cloth cut-out or something else entirely. If someone has seen a Crawford-esque link, a description in any module or book or something else to go on, please let us know. Also, if there are official rules on how much space they **must** take up (and what actions they are capable of), please make it known (and thank you).

Comment: While all shadow related, I think you've got too many questions tied up in this.

Comment: I think this should be split into at least two questions - one regarding what they are made of and the other regarding their capabilities.

Comment: I am thankful with the answers i have below. I am sorry that the question, as written, does not meet your (?) collective standards. It must be a weird job, being a moderator and i wish you the best of luck with that.

Comment: @TimofTime: StackExchange is largely "self-moderated" by the community, with diamond mods like me just being exception handlers. This question was closed as a result of votes from the community. If you edit your question to focus on one overall issue as suggested by the regular users above, it can likely be reopened; you can ask any other questions you have separately. See this meta for more info: [1 post - 1 question , is it a rule or a guideline or what?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6453/1-post-1-question-is-it-a-rule-or-a-guideline-or-what)

Answer (score 5):

### It is amorphous

> Dictionary definition:
>   a·mor·phous (adjective); əˈmôrfəs
>   *without a clearly defined shape or form*

That means that its substance and consistency is changeable.  This is similar to, but not the same as, [the Mimic's unique nature: it too is amorphous](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/74317/22566)(although the mimic isn't undead).  The shadow isn't incorporeal.  If the shadow were incorporeal, or able to become so, it would be able to move through things as a specter does.

> [Incorporeal Movement{specter}](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/specter) . The specter can move through other creatures and objects as if they were difficult terrain. It takes 5 (1d10) force damage if it ends its turn inside an object. {a ghost and a wraith also has this feature}

Let's look at [a few important features](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/shadow)

> SHADOW, Medium undead, chaotic evil
>   Skills Stealth +4 (+6 in dim light or darkness)
>   **Damage Vulnerabilities** radiant
>   **Damage Resistances** acid, cold, fire, lightning, thunder; bludgeoning, piercing, and slashing from nonmagical attacks
>   **Damage Immunities** necrotic, poison
>   **Condition Immunities** exhaustion, frightened, ***grappled, paralyzed, petrified***, poisoned, ***prone, restrained***

Note that mundane weapons *can* damage it, so it has *some* substance to it.
What does being amorphous allow the shadow to do?

> **Amorphous**. The shadow can move through a space as narrow as 1 inch wide without squeezing.

Vampires in mist form and water elementals can do something similar, and yet each is of a different consistency.

- I like to describe a shadow's consistency as "like thick smoke" so
  that you get the idea of what it would feel like, but that it needs
  to flow around things (like walls) rather than flow through things
  (the way that a specter can).
- You could also describe its consistency as "thick fog" and get close
  to what it seems to be made of.

  The MM leaves the precise description up to the DM.

> **Shadow Stealth**. While in dim light or darkness, the shadow can take
>   the Hide action as a bonus action.
>   **Sunlight Weakness**. While in sunlight, the shadow has disadvantage on attack rolls, ability checks, and saving throws.

The final, and somewhat unsatisfying, answer is that a shadow is "nearly insubstantial" such that you can't get a grip on it, knock it down, or otherwise restrain it.  It is *amorphous*.

---

As to how many shadows fit in a phone booth: what's a phone booth?  8^D  All kidding aside, that will depend on the size of the phone booth, and how many shadows the DM needs to fit into it.

Comment: I still wonder if the things take falling damage, sink under water, would pour into a large bucket or if they are even able to climb a rough wall. Slippery? Oozy? No idea. That said, the answer to my most curious questions is not in any rulebook. My thanks for your excellent attempt!

Comment: @TimofTime do they take falling damage?  Great question, maybe post that one?  Sink under water?  I don't think so, looks like a DM call.  Climb a wall?  Probably.(Given that they flow).  I am glad that you are asking these questions since I have an encounter with a bunch of shadows in a mine looming in about two sessions from now: you have my brain working!  8^D

Comment: In D&D terms, a phone booth must be one 5×5 square. After all, "a knife fight in a phone booth" is supposed to be difficult, and characters have disadvantage when fighting while squeezing. Then again, under the rules you can't voluntarily end your move in another creature's space, so a knife fight in a phone booth may not be possible RAW. :)

Comment: @T.J.L. Unless a swarm learns how to wield a knife 8^o

Comment: Perhaps a... butterfly knife? :)

Comment: @T.J.L. *golf clap* well played!  8^D

Answer (score 2):

## It isn't specified

According to the description in the *Monster Manual*, a shadow is made from... the literal shadow of the creature from which it was born.  Of course, that doesn't make sense for any number of reasons, but the game does not attempt to simulate reality.  Given that we can't really infer anything from this, we must look at the shadow's stat block.

The shadow is resistant to physical non-magical damage, and cannot be grappled.  Yet it cannot pass through objects, so it is not fully incorporeal.  There is also no restriction on its *ability to* grapple (though a GM can of course decide otherwise.)

Interestingly, these properties closely mirror those of a water elemental.  You might infer that the shadow has the consistency of a fluid, with the ability to shape itself in order to make attacks and so on.

The one difference is that it does not share the water elemental's ability to stay in a hostile creature's space.  Unlike the elemental, a shadow has a distinct form, and cannot attempt to "contain" another creature in this way.

#### In summary

A shadow is capable of taking any action that it is not explicitly forbidden to take.  It can climb, and it can grapple.  If the GM decides that this is inconsistent with their idea of what the shadow is, they have the ability to determine otherwise.

Shadows are discrete creatures, and while they can move through small openings with little difficulty, there is no indication that they can reduce their volume (they can reshape, but are most likely incompressible.)  It would be reasonable to assume that you could fit more of them in one place than you could an equivalently sized human, but there is no further guidance than that.  This is firmly in GM fiat territory.